# Executable runs from terminal but fails within application

Tags: qt, ubuntu, environment-variables, .so

I have created a sample project to test my dynamic library (.so) in Linux Ubuntu.

The program compiles correctly and runs when launching from terminal. It works as expected - In terminal `./Main` finds all dependencies and functions.

When launching from within QT (Build/Run) I get the error:  `Cannot open a_dependent_library.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

My environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains the directory where `a_dependent_library.so` is located

Please advise.

Comment: Is `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in the environment that QtCreator was launched in?
Alternatively, you can set it in Project -> Kit / Run

Comment: I already have a cmake file, using it I am creating Qt project.

Is there a way to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in cmake ? (I was supposing it should pick the a_dependent_library.so itself, as its directory is already in LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: I tried this in cmake file:

link_directories(../lib) (this only works with absolute path, which I ideally don't want) and then using -la_dependent_library in target_link_libraries resolves the error but with absolute path only

Comment: Not sure what cmake has to do with the environment, it generates your build files. You said you had `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set, but maybe that is just in the shell you are executing the program from

Answer (score 1):

make sure to add the env variable in QTCreator ---> Projects --> Execute tab (Not compile tab) ---> execution environement --->add yours.

These are the env variables used in Run of the qt project.